# Issue while setting background resource for second time

Tags: android

I am facing issue while setting background.

I have the condition like below:-

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedRgbArray[3].getCode())) {
    color_3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(selectedRgbArray[3].getValue()));
} else {
    color_3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_palette);
}
```

In the above condition by default compiler goes in else condition but after a button click it again goes in second condition, for first time it works perfectly but  second time it sets gray background which cannot be as `bg_palette` is a `gray border drawable`.

**bg_palette.xml** is below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/size_01"
        android:color="@color/light_grey" />
    <corners android:radius="0dip" />

</shape>
```

Please help me getting my mistake over there.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code .

1.add color to the colors

```
<color name="color_white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

2.set it to solid

```
<solid android:color="@color/color_white" />
```

**EDIT**

Add `android:shape="rectangle"` of shape xml code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
```

And you can change to other shape .

Comment: I got the answer by trying color filter to my background :)

Comment: @Aditi than ans your self for this question

Comment: You can check it .@Aditi

Comment: Check my answer please .@Aditi

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone it found the solution by setting color filter to background

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedRgbArray[3].getCode())) {
     color_1.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(selectedRgbArray[1].getValue()), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
} else {
    color_1.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
}
```

I have set background by tint color and it works.